# Pinescript Beginner Strategy not generating orders?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am a total beginner in Pinescript, and I tried to create a super-simple strategy to enter a long position whenever a new low pivot point is higher than the previous pivot point. However, this strategy does not generate any orders. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
//@version=5
strategy("HigherLows", overlay=true, margin_long=100, margin_short=100)
int leftleg = input(3)
int rightleg = input(3)

var float newLow = na
var float prevLow = na

pivotLowPrice= ta.pivotlow(leftleg, rightleg)
if not na(pivotLowPrice)
    newLow := pivotLowPrice
    if not na(prevLow)
        if newLow > prevLow
            strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, 1)
    prevLow := pivotLowPrice
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It generates an order but you don't close your position. So, it is always in a position.

[image]

You should use `strategy.exit()` or `strategy.close()` to exit your position.